# Getting the price of the game from EGS

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm trying to get the price of the game from the epic games store, but I get a 403 error

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://store.epicgames.com/ru/p/cities-skylines"

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    price_element = soup.find(class_='css-119zqif')

    if price_element is not None:
        price = price_element.get_text(strip=True) 
        print("Price Cities: Skylines:", price)
    else:
        print("Error")
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code)
```

I tried to access the game page directly, and take the price information from the class in html, but I get the error "Request error: 403"

Comment: May be specific to the epic games site. I tested with the base page as well as other web pages and only the epic games webpage returned error 403. Since error 403 is a "permission denied" error, it may be specific to their site implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get to the cloudflare page dedicated to fighting robots. To get around this limitation, you need to imitate a real person. To do this, you can use the [following library](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/VeNoMouS-cloudscraper-python-web-crawling) or similar. Here is an example of working code. Don't forget to `pip install cloudscraper`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cloudscraper

url = "https://store.epicgames.com/ru/p/cities-skylines"

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
response = scraper.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    price_element = soup.find('div', 'css-169q7x3').find(class_='css-119zqif')
    print(price_element)

    if price_element is not None:
        price = price_element.get_text(strip=True) 
        print("Price Cities: Skylines:", price)
    else:
        print("Error")
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code)
```

result:

```
Price Cities: Skylines: 330 ₽
```

One remark. This library has free limitations and sometimes an error may occur: `cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareChallengeError: Detected a Cloudflare version 2 Captcha challenge, This feature is not available in the opensource (free) version.` Ignore it and get the result. But you can always rewrite your code [using this API](https://scrapingant.com/). If you sign up, they will give you a token for 10,000 requests per month. If this option does not suit you, look in the direction of [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).